# Nothing adds or subtracts-js calculator

Tags: javascript, html, input, calculator

What's wrong here? Because it does not show an error and nothing is displayed. It tries to find it and it doesn't work for me, it needs such arrangement, etc.

```html
<body>
    <form name="xD">
        Number 1: <input type="text" name="txtnum1" id="txtnum1">
        <br>
        Number 2: <input type="text" name="txtnum2" id="txtnum2">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="ok" onlick="sumValues()">
        <p id="dodawanie">addition </p>
        <p id="odejmowanie">subtraction</p>
        <p id="mnozenie">division </p>
        <p id="dzielenie">multiplication </p>
    </form>
    <script>
        function sumValues() {
    var wymiarx, wymiary;
    wymiarx=Number(document.xD.txtnum1.value);
    wymiary=Number(document.xD.txtnum2.value);

            // var wymiarx = txtnum1.value;
            //var wymiary = txtnum2.value;

var dodawanie1 = wymiarx + wymiary;
var odejmowanie1 = wymiarx - wymiary;
var mnozenie1 = wymiarx * wymiary;
var dzielenie1 = wymiarx / wymiary;

document.getElementById("dodawanie").innerHTML = "addition" + dodawanie1;
document.getElementById("odejmowanie").innerHTML = "subtraction " + odejmowanie1;
document.getElementById("mnozenie").innerHTML = "division " + mnozenie1;
document.getElementById("dzielenie").innerHTML = "multiplication " + dzielenie1;
}
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Explain more...

Comment: Did you try with the `onclick` atttribute? Because `onlick` certainly does nothing...

Answer (score 2):

the mistake maybe? you said onlick instead of onclick

> <input type="button" value="ok" **onlick**="sumValues()">